# Are there any benefits of using hazel cast over Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, scalability, hazelcast, nosql

I want to implement session store for my web application. Here's the profile of my application.

1. The information associated with a session does not change a lot, but
   it does change sometimes.
2. Session reads(session.getAttribute()) are more frequent than writes(session.setAttribute()).
3. I don't want to deal with master node based architecture(like redis).
4. Data associated with a session is small, but the number of sessions could be large.
5. The lookup is always in the form of key value like in hash map.
6. I am OK with eventual consistency.
7. I want to be able to specify the replication factor. i.e. number of nodes that will hold data for a given session
8. I am only looking for open source solutions that wouldn't incur license cost for above features.
9. For now I want to store upto 10,000 sessions with 10kb data per session(on average), but eventually I want to scale to 100,000 sessions or more!

In my app hazelcast is already being used for some other functionality. But I don't want that to be the deciding factor. Cassandra seems to fulfill all my requirements and it seems to be quite popular. Any reason I should chose hazelcast over cassandra?

Comment: Be careful with points 1 & 2. Sessions are write-heavy. Every time you process a web request the session's last access time must be updated, whether or not you access the session attributes for read or write.

Comment: @NeilStevenson Thanks for pointing out last access time. I almost missed that part.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Disclaimer: Hazelcast employee

In general I would argue that if you can exchange Hazelcast with Cassandra OR Cassandra with Hazelcast, one of the tools is misused.
We have plenty of people using them as companions, meaning Cassandra as the storage layer and Hazelcast as the caching layer, Cassandra, however, is not a cache and Hazelcast is not a database.

If you want to persist your storages to disk, go for Cassandra (maybe add caching with Hazelcast), if you just want to distribute, go with Hazelcast. Latter case especially if it "doesn't really matter" if you loose sessions once in a while if you (for some reason or another) restart the cluster.

Answer (score 6):

We use both of them in our project. We use Cassandra as persistent storage and Hazelcast for temporary and frequently changed data (e.g. distributed queues and synchronization primitives).

> Any reason I should chose hazelcast over cassandra?

In my opinion, Hazelcast is easier from developer point of view and it does not require as much attention as Cassandra on production environment (deep configuration and tunning, repeair, restarting...), so Hazelcast is cheaper in support.